# Python Pyomo: Simple optimization problem with variables in Boolean statement

Tags: python, boolean, constraints, pyomo, piecewise

I would like to know whether it is possible to use Pyomo to solve such a problem:

variables: z (bounds = (0,1), S, sq, Loc1

> sq = -z*(z-1)
>
> if (z <= Loc1-0.2 or z >= Loc1+0.2): S = 0
>
> else if z <= Loc1: S = 0.6 * (z - Loc1 + 0.2)/0.2
>
> else: S = 0.6 * (Loc1 + 0.2 - z)/0.2
>
> maximize(S*sq)

S is according to this definition nonzero between Loc1 - 0.2 and Loc + 0.2, rises from 0 at (Loc - 0.2) to 0.6 at Loc1 and then back to 0 at (Loc1 + 0.2).

sq is a quadratic function with roots at 0 and 1 and a maximum sq (z = 0.5) = 0.25.

So the solution to the problem would be z = 0.5, Loc1 = 0.5, sq = 0.25 and S = 0.6 (at these locations both sq and S have their maximum).

I tried to use a Piecewise linear constraint but the problem is that using variables in a Boolean expression ( e.g. if z < m.Loc1 - 0.2) is invalid and value(m.Loc1) only uses the initialized value of m.Loc1. Is there a way to define a Piecewise function or a formulation with Disjuncts which allow using a variable to define the domains of a piecewise function?

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: it works with something like this:

```html
from pyomo.environ import *


m = ConcreteModel()
m.z = Var(bounds=(0,1))
m.S = Var() 
m.sq = Var()
m.Loc1 = Var(initialize=0.65)

def sq_func(m):
        return m.sq == -(m.z)*(m.z-1)
m.sqcon = Constraint(rule=sq_func)

rangep = [0,0,0.6,0,0]

bpts=[0,0.3,m.Loc1,0.8,1]
m.source=Piecewise(m.S,m.z,pw_pts=bpts,pw_repn='DCC',pw_constr_type='EQ',f_rule=rangep)

def obj(m):
    return m.S*m.sq
m.obj = Objective(rule = obj,sense=maximize)


results = SolverFactory('ipopt').solve(m)
print("Loc1: ",value(m.Loc1), "\nz: ", value(m.z), "\nS: ",value(m.S), "\nsq: ",value(m.sq),"\nS*sq: ",value(m.sq)*value(m.S))
```